# Change the content of a cell from another cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hey,
i'm trying to select change the content of a cell with jquery but i cant seem to get it working. lets say we have this table:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>cell 1
<td>cell 2
<td>cell 3
<tr>
<td>cell 4
<td>cell 5
<td>cell 6 <a onclick="javascript:$(this).parent().parent().('td').html('test');">Click</a>
<tr>
<td>cell 7
<td>cell 8
<td>cell 9
</table>
```

i want to change the content of cell 4 from within cell 6. the ('td') obviously isnt working. how can i access cell 4 from cell 6 without the use of classes or ids?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want this instead since you want to go up one, and back two.

```
$(this).parent().prev().prev().html('test');
```

or like this:

```
$(this).parent().prevAll(':last').html('test');
```

or this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings(':first-child').html('test');
```

...or you could do it pretty easily without jQuery:

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the javascript to be:

$(this).parent().parent().**children('td').eq(0)**.html('test');

This gets the first child td of the table row (cell 4), and sets the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the 4th `<td>` in your table, you can go up to the `closest` table, and then `find` the 4th `<td>` inside it. Then you can change its HTML.

```
$(this).closest('table').find('td:eq(3)').html('test');
```

[**Live Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/uVWBS/)